# set a default value in user form django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I need an additional default value in user form but it will not be  asked  from user it will be saved in every user's data by default but  how can I do it ? 
This is my form

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, min_length=6) 
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(), min_length=6) 
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30) 
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30) 
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254)
```

Comment: This is something you need to change in models.py. What is the field you want to add?

Comment: When you call your form in views, you can assign an initial value to the field

Comment: A single integer value basically it will act as a counter and i will change it value dynamically.

Comment: By default I want it to be set to 1

Comment: What is the field? where exactly in your form

Comment: It it not in this form as I have to create it and don't know how to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I understand what you were asking. If you are going to use a ModelForm you should look here into how the class meta: works for [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#a-full-example) This should get you started with having an additional field in the form. If you are adding some extra data to the User model you will need to extend the user model with [AbstractUser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project)and add the 'additional_field'.

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, min_length=6)
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(), min_length=6)
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254)
    additional_field = forms.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['additional_field'].disabled = True
        self.fields['additional_field'].initial = 'SOME INITIAL VALUE'
```

Comment: It created the user but can I print this filed in templates?

Comment: If you extended the User model with the AbstractUser you should simply be able to run `{{ user.additional_field }}`. If you wanted to provide your view and all other relevant code that would help.

Comment: It created the user but field is not saved in user's data, when I access it says no "additional_field". I was trying to avoid AbstractUser but seems will have to.

Comment: You can avoid AbstractUser by doing an intermediate OneToOne user table that will hold extra non-authentication related data about a user. I would recommend doing that then you could very easily add the extra field from above to that extended OneToOne user model.

Comment: I can provide and example if you would like.

Comment: Oh yes, I just realized it would be a better option, Thankyou for help.